# Can't create and active Virtualenv in windows 10 , python 37

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am new in Python and to be coder :) I am trying to create and active virtualenv, searching for days to fix this problem but I couldn't, can you help me pls..

Thank you.

Let me show you my administrator:

````
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\büşra\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37'
New python executable in C:\Users\Büşra\Desktop\Django-Virtualenv\myenv\Scripts\python.exe
Complete output from command C:\Users\Büşra\Deskt...v\Scripts\python.exe -m pip config list:
Could not import runpy module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'runpy'
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Büşra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 793, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1087, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 935, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 964, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    config = _pip_config(py_executable, python_path)
  File "c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1038, in _pip_config
    remove_from_env=["PIP_VERBOSE", "PIP_QUIET"],
  File "c:\users\büşra\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 886, in call_subprocess
    raise OSError("Command {} failed with error code {}".format(cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command C:\Users\Büşra\Deskt...v\Scripts\python.exe -m pip config list failed with error code 1```
````

Comment: I'm not a big fan of pip's vitrualenv but it shouldn't require much fanagling to get working.  As van der Zon Stef mentioned, you need to activate the virtual environment before you can use it. `source myenv/bin/activate` is how you would activate the environment.  You may also try making sure that runpy is installed, since that is what is in your traceback.  `pip show runpy` will return your version info if it's there and return nothing if it isn't.  Personally, I like to use `conda` for this sort of stuff, rather than pip.  `conda create -n myenv`, `conda activate myenv`, boom, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

On a windows machine you would activate the virtual environment as follows:
cd into the project directory, if your virtual environment is named venv then this 
venv\scripts\activate will activate the virtual environment